# How to use kotlin functional programming to access a property

Tags: unit-testing, kotlin, closures

I currently have the following function:

```
fun createMask(mask : String){
    val ssnField : mywidgets.SSNField = findViewById (R.id.editTextText)
    ssnField.hint = mask
}
```

To unit test this I want to wrap the untestable code within createMask into a closure. (The untestable code is the view layer logic that's difficult to instantiate and execute in a unit test.) Here is what I want to do in **pseudo code**:

```
createMask(closure, mask : String){
    closure = mask  // closure function returns pointer to property (depending on closure return type, might need to use setter: closure.set(mask))
}
```

With the above, the caller then does:

```
fun caller(){
    createMask((){
        val ssnField : mywidgets.SSNField = findViewById (R.id.editTextText)
        return ssnField.hint
    }, "xxx-xx-xxx")
}
```

How do do what is expressed in pseudo code work in kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return a reference of the property if you make `createMask` accept a parameter of type `() -> KMutableProperty0<String>`. Then you can call the [`set`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-mutable-property0/set.html) method:

```
fun createMask(mask : String, block: () -> KMutableProperty0<String>) {
    block().set(mask)
}

// caller

createMask("xxx-xx-xxx") {
    val ssnField = ...
    ssnField::hint
}
```

Alternatively, use `(String) -> Unit` to represent "any function that takes a string", if you want to allow callers to pass any function that has the "form" of a setter.

```
fun createMask(mask : String, block: () -> (String) -> Unit) {
    block()(mask)
}

// caller

createMask("xxx-xx-xxx") {
    val ssnField = ...
    ssnField::hint.setter
}
```

Note that this method involves reflection, which may not be desirable. Alternatively, you can accept a closure that takes the string to be set, and let the caller set it in the closure:

```
fun createMask(mask: String, block: (String) -> Unit) {
    block(mask)
}

// caller

createMask("xxx-xx-xxx") {
    val ssnField = ...
    // note that rather than responsible for returning a property, the caller 
    // is responsible for setting "it" to the property
    ssnField.hint = it
}
```

(I'm assuming `createMask` does more than just setting a property. Otherwise it is quite pointless...)

Comment: Thanks Sweeper, this looks super promising. Let me give this a shot then I'll mark the answer, "answered" if it works, which I think it will.

Comment: BTW, what references do you suggest I read to get more familiar with function pointers, KMutableProperty, Unit etc? I find the Kotlin functional syntax not very intuitive (versus Javascript for example or Python).

Comment: @LanceKind Here are some links: [Higher order functions and lambas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html), [KMutableProperty](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-mutable-property/). `Unit` isn't really a complicated thing. It's just like `void` in other languages to mean "no return value".

Comment: I'm going to give this answer a try live on TDD.Academy this Friday at 4:30ET: https://www.twitch.tv/tddacademy
https://m.youtube.com/channel/UCU1U6oPscxzKd_IWAIOm60w

Comment: thanks for the references!

Comment: @LanceKind I'm watching your stream. Just do `createMask(mask, {mutablePropertyHere::myProperty })` Note the `::`. That makes it a `KMutableProperty0<String>`.

Comment: Sweeper, your calls to createMask don't pass in the function reference.  The calls to createMask require two parameters. I'm stuck on getting the syntax right for passing in a reference to the parameter.  Could you update the answer to show the correct call to createMask?

Comment: @LanceKind I didn’t expect that you didn’t know anything about lambdas or function types. You should probably read [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas), most importantly [this section](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#passing-trailing-lambdas). I _did_ pass the second parameter.

Comment: thanks a ton for your support on StackOverflow and the comments here to get me on track during the show. I learned a TON with this one because higher order functions (or as it turned out, reflection) was needed to decouple the code to drive unit tests. Thanks! And thanks for the doc references.

Comment: Regarding my comment about second parameter, I'm not sure you noticed in your answer above that your calls to *createMask* only pass in one parameter (the mask) and not the closure as well. I appreciate that you gave three different styles. You know your stuff.